# how to pass the overlayProps into Panel

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

How can I pass the styles overlayProps into the Panel component as it is stated in  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/panel

I tried:

```
<Panel
    overlayProps={{styles:{backgroundColor:'red'}}}
/>
```

But does not seems to work

Comment: *But does not seems to work*: some elaboration would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing missing from the original source is `root`, which is the target element in the overlay.

This snippet (full example) shows a `Panel` with a red overlay. ([full example](https://codepen.io/jdh-msft/pen/YzwXKqG?editors=0010))

```tsx
const PanelBasicExample: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Panel
        headerText="Sample panel"
        isOpen={true}
        overlayProps={{ className: "foo", styles: { root: { backgroundColor: "red" }}}}
      >
        <p>Content goes here.</p>
      </Panel>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`layerProps` is an optional props to pass to the ***Layer component*** hosting the panel.Do you have a Layer Component?

Also, `styles` can have a `className` as properties, you may try to give the component a customised name and adapt the css.

Comment: even the className , how am i going to pass it in order to be used as a prop. overlayProps={{className:"testClassName"}} is not working either

Answer (score -1):

i guess you can check out the "Panel - custom navigation" provided in your link.

it has something like below to override searchbox. I think Panel should be the same since it also accepts a similar styles prop.

```
const searchboxStyles = { root: { margin: '5px', height: 'auto', width: '100%' } };
  <SearchBox
        placeholder="Search here..."
        styles={searchboxStyles}
        ariaLabel="Sample search box. Does not actually search anything."
      />
```